# LateInitializationError: Field 'error' has not been initialized for a class model

Tags: flutter, if-statement

I'm am writing my first Flutter project but getting this error

```
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'APIResponse<bool>' which excludes null.
 - 'APIResponse' is from 'package:notesapp/APIResponse/APIResponse.dart' ('lib/APIResponse/APIResponse.dart').
                 message = deleteResult?.errorMessage ?? 'An error occured';
```

This is the model class

```
class APIResponse <T> {
 late T data;
 late bool error;
 late String errorMessage;

 APIResponse({ data, error, errorMessage});
```

}

And this is where I'm calling this model

```
noteListService.getSingleNote(widget.noteId).then((response) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        if( response.error ){
          errorMessage = response.errorMessage ?? 'An error occured';
        }
        singleNoteModel = response.data;
        _titleController.text = singleNoteModel.noteTitle;
        _contentController.text = singleNoteModel.noteContent;
      });
```

It throws the error at this particular place - `errorMessage = response.errorMessage ?? 'An error occured';`

Answer (score 0):

The top copy/pasted code is not actually an error but a warning and won't stop function of your app.

It's also not the same piece of code you're mentioning at bottom of question, nor in the title, which is related to `response.errorMessage`.  The top warning is about `deleteResult?.errorMessage`.

Anyways, it appears that the `APIResponse` object, its `error` boolean field hasn't been set when your app hits the line marked by `↓**This line**↓`:

```
noteListService.getSingleNote(widget.noteId).then((response) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        // ↓**This line**↓ will throw if 'error' has not yet been set.
        if( response.error ){
          errorMessage = response.errorMessage ?? 'An error occured';
        }
        singleNoteModel = response.data;
        _titleController.text = singleNoteModel.noteTitle;
        _contentController.text = singleNoteModel.noteContent;
      });
```

One resolution would be to not define the `error` boolean as `late`, but just a regular `bool` and giving it a starting value of `false`.  Would that wreck the logic of your app?  I would assume the app isn't in an error state to begin with, so logically this should be OK?

I believe this will prevent `if ( response.error )` from throwing when reached.

```
class APIResponse <T> {
 late T data;
 bool error = false; // Give it a default value of false
 late String errorMessage;

 APIResponse({ data, error, errorMessage});
```